# Add Permision to Send Message on Odoo15

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

i am trying to inherit the mail.chatterTopbar on so i can add a permission so not all the users can send a message to the partner.

i tryed this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve" id="template">
    <t t-name="custom_chatter" t-extend="mail.ChatterTopbar">
        <t t-jquery=".o_ChatterTopbar_buttonSendMessage" t-operation="replace">
            <button class="btn btn-link">Test Me</button>
        </t>
    </t>

</templates>
```

this just to test if it worked but haven't work, i already tried adding it to the manifest as data and as qweb in static/src/xml/sendblock_template.xml but without luck :D

Answer (score 0):

Use [extension inherit mode](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/frontend/qweb.html#template-inheritance) to transform template inplace

***Example:***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-inherit="mail.ChatterTopbar" t-inherit-mode="extension">
        <xpath
            expr="//button[@class='btn btn-link o_ChatterTopbar_button o_ChatterTopbar_buttonSendMessage']"
            position="replace"
        >
            <t t-if="chatter.canSend">
              <button
                class="btn btn-link o_ChatterTopbar_button"
                type="button"
                t-att-disabled="chatter.isDisabled"
                t-on-click="_onButtonClick"
              >
                  Test Me
              </button>
            </t>
         </xpath>
    </t>
</templates>
```

To be able to use `chatter.canSend`, extend the chatter model to add a new field

***Example:***

```js
/** @odoo-module **/
import { registerFieldPatchModel, registerInstancePatchModel } from "@mail/model/model_core";
import { attr } from "@mail/model/model_field";
import session from 'web.session';

registerInstancePatchModel(
    "mail.chatter",
    "{MODULE_NAME}/static/src/js/chatter.js",
    {
        _created() {
            var self = this;
            this._super(...arguments);
            session.user_has_group("{MODULE_NAME}.can_send_messages").then(function(has_group){
                self.update({'canSend': has_group});
            });
        },
    }
);

registerFieldPatchModel("mail.chatter", "{MODULE_NAME}/static/src/js/chatter.js", {
    canSend: attr({
        default: false,
    }),
});
```

To use the `_onButtonClick` function, you can extend the `chatter_topbar` component

***Example:***

```js
/** @odoo-module **/
import { ChatterTopbar } from "@mail/components/chatter_topbar/chatter_topbar";
import { patch } from "web.utils";
const components = { ChatterTopbar };



patch(
    components.ChatterTopbar.prototype,
    "{MODULE_NAME}/static/src/js/chatter_topbar.esm.js",
    {
        _onButtonClick(ev) {

        },
    }
);
```

Add the js files under `'web.assets_qweb'`